# How to visually represent 2 kinds of events (one time and repeating)?

Tags: image

There are 2 kinds of events:

1. the **single** event, which once you finish it, it disappears (e.g.
   a workshop)
2. the **repeating** event, that stays alive after you finish it (e.g.
       work or classes)

I'm representing these events with a rectangle like this:

```
        |  Name
  Date  |                        [IMAGE]
        |  Description
```

I want to insert an image into the [IMAGE] rectangle, that tells if the event is **single** or **repeating**, but I don't know a good pair of images to represent them (although I thought **repeating** could be something like ↻).

Would it be better if I let the **single** event without image and use that for **repeating** or there is a good pair of images that I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the room, you could just be explicit with a text label, since an image still needs some decoding from the user.

**You can indicate:**

- The cycle (Weekly, Biweekly, Monthly, etc.)
- The day ('Every Monday', 'Every first Thursday')

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK1n3m.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>